# Java Tiled map is painting sideways

Tags: java, arraylist, java-2d

Recently I've been trying to make a little game for my learning purpose but I got stuck. I was able to generate a map from a .txt file but then it seems to paint it sideways?

this is my map loaded which reads from a text file and add them to an ArrayList.
Width is 20 Height is 10. Same thing applies in my map 20 lines wide 10 down.

```
public void loadMap(String name) {
        try {
            this.name = name;

            FileInputStream file_stream = new FileInputStream(name);
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(file_stream);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

            map = new Tile[WIDTH][HEIGHT];

            String line;
            int y = 0;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] tokens = line.split(" ");
                for (int x = 0; x < WIDTH; x++) {
                    boolean f = false;
                    if (Integer.parseInt(tokens[x]) == 1)
                        f = true;
                    Tile tile = new Tile(y, x, f, Integer.parseInt(tokens[x]));
                    tiles.add(tile);
                    map[x][y] = tile;
                    System.out.println("adding tile (x: " + x + " y: " + y + ") " + f + " " + Integer.parseInt(tokens[x]));
                }
                y++;
            }
            in.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The map: " + name + " was not found.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

This is the draw method for the map

```
public void paint(Graphics2D g) {
        for (Tile t : getTiles()) {
            t.draw(g);
        //g.draw(t.getBounds());
        }
    }
```

Here is an example map

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

The way it paints the map is basically a vertical version of this instead of the correct way like it is above. I have tried messing with the numbers within the mapLoaded (width, height) and switching the x and y around but nothing seems to work. Please help

Comment: Where are you initializing the `tiles` ArrayList?

Comment: private Tile[][] map;
private ArrayList<Tile> tiles = new ArrayList<Tile>();

Those are where the variables are at. map is initialied within mapLoader

Comment: What is the purpose of the `ArrayList<Tile>` when you already have all of the `Tile`s stored in an array?

Comment: Could you please include the getTiles method and also, I can't seem to find the Tile docs anywhere - is I part of Graphics2D? Could you link me so I could take a look at the constructor? Thanks.

Comment: @JoshM they aren't store in the Tile[][]. they are stored in the array list. the Tie[][] is just for map size

Comment: @user2023050 What!? `map[x][y] = tile;`?

Comment: @JacobKudria
public ArrayList<Tile> getTiles() {
  return tiles;
 }
And the Tile is my class.
public Tile(final int x, final int y, final boolean unrestricted, final int graphicsId)

Comment: @user2023050 What happens if you reverse the x and y in this line: `Tile tile = new Tile(y, x, f, Integer.parseInt(tokens[x]));`

Comment: @JacobKudria You fixed my problem! (: Cheers bro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to change `Tile tile = new Tile(y, x, f, Integer.parseInt(tokens[x]));` to
`Tile tile = new Tile(x, y, f, Integer.parseInt(tokens[x]));`.

Everytime you're making a new Tile, you're switching x and y which is causing your problems.